# How to retrieve random folders?

Tags: php, random

I have three folders, each of these folders have 40 tasks each. I have to randomise these folders, which I have done by using `shuffle($folder)` and then storing it in a session array.

But the issue I'm finding is how can I retrieve them afterwards, for example when a user clicks on start experiment:

It'll go the first trial, at this point it'll look at the first array then it'll choose the correct folder from the switch statement and it'll start the test.

But then I'm having problems going to the second and third folders, and since they'll be randomised each time I can't point the folders to a specified location.

I know this sounds confusing, so if you need more details, please let me know. I haven't posted the code and there is quite a bit, but if anyone wants to see what I've done so far I'll set up a dropbox link so you can view the various files.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l98z3mzk4cd2105/qxz09lWOM9

Edit:

Thank you all you guys that helped, I haven't fully sorted it out yet, but the suggestion have certainly helped. Thank You. I'll post a full update when I manage to get it working.

Comment: folders as in directories? What data structures are we talking about?

Comment: Interesting - is this an assignment question? I recall assisting someone with almost the exact same scenario several months ago. Folders full of tasks, randomize the folders, but perform folder tasks in order?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That was me, I still havent managed to finish the site, since I had started working. But No this isn't an assignment question, it's just that I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without understanding how you're implementing what it is you've explained.

So you're shuffling an array of folder names, and you want the user to access a random folder, or all three folders in a random order?

Why are you having problems going to the 2nd and 3rd folder?

You need to be more specific about what it is you're trying to do, and what's going wrong with your implementation.

Edit: Madara Uchiha understood what you meant it seems. I wasn't sure if you were accessing all 3 folders consecutively (in which case you could just loop through $folder using a foreach loop after shuffling it), or access a random unique folder every time the user submitted the form. If it's the latter, then Madara Uchiha has answered your question :)

Edit: Could you do this?

```
shuffle($folder);
foreach($folder as $element)
{
    // $element is your random folder
    // ...
}
```

You'd go through each folder only once, until the loop ends. You could have as many folders as you like. It's just cycling through each element in the array.

Comment: What it is, is that I want the user to access all three folders in a random order, whilst recording the data into the mysql database, at the momement I'm implementing it like this: 

Start >> FirstTrial >> Submit Data >> SecondTrial >> Submit Data 
etc..

Comment: Could you not use a loop to go through each element in your array after shuffling it?

Comment: Why do want to search the path of a folder ? You just have 3 folders. Define their paths and randomize their paths using an array. Refer my solution below.

Comment: @MartynShutt Thank You. This has helped a lot, don't know why I didn't think of this before. But Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, after starting a test, remove the entry which was used from the `$folders` array. That way, even if it's re-randomized, you won't have repetitions.:)

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution for you.

```
$folders = array(
                array("foldername"=>"folder1","folderpath"=>"path_to_folder1"),
                array("foldername"=>"folder2","folderpath"=>"path_to_folder2"),
                array("foldername"=>"folder3","folderpath"=>"path_to_folder3"),


);

$randomFolderNo = rand(0,2);

$selectedFolder = $folders[$randomFolderNo];

echo $selectedFolderName = $selectedFolder['foldername'];
echo $selectedFolderPath = $selectedFolder['folderpath'];
```

You can use the $folder array in your SESSION array.